# Show Properties on far right of IDE in VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to follow a tutorial where the teacher clicks the properties button on the far right
under *"server Explorer, Toolbox*" of the VS IDE. I do not have this and can not figure out how to enable it.

Example:
[image]

Everything I can find on google tells me to go to View->Properties, but this is not the same window that the teacher brings up.

I am trying to bring up the properties of the CLI form I created for a GUI.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View --> other windows --> Properties Window (alt+Enter)

[image]

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.